# Is there any cannibalism in Mirai Nikki (Future Dairy)?

Tags: mirai-nikki

I'm trying to suggest *Mirai Nikki* (Future Dairy) to a friend but they really don't like cannibalism but they're cool with the killing and all that.

So is there any cannibalism in *Mirai Nikki*?

Comment: uh... that will be very hard to prove but there is no such thing as cannibalism in Mirai Nikki.

Answer (score 4):

Having read the manga and watched the anime, I can say with some certainty that there is no cannibalism in *Mirai Nikki*.

Your friend might have suspected such thing due to the fanbase surrounding *Mirai Nikki*, which often creates AMV's and tributes using the song ["Cannibal"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mp0o3xjmHnQ) by Kesha.